# Unable to mock using spy

Tags: angular

```
import { ValidatorsService } from 'services/ValidatorsService.ts';
import { AppConstants } from 'app.constants';
import { AlertsService } from 'services/AlertsService';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

fdescribe('Validators service', function() {
  let vs: ValidatorsService = null;
  let appConstantsSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<AppConstants>;
  beforeEach(() => {
    console.log('Nitish');
    const spy = jasmine.createSpyObj(
        'AppConstants', ['INVALID_NAME_CHARS']);
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [ValidatorsService,
      AlertsService,
      {provide: AppConstants, useValue: spy}]
    });

    vs = TestBed.get(ValidatorsService);
    appConstantsSpy = TestBed.get(AppConstants);
    appConstantsSpy.INVALID_NAME_CHARS.and.returnValue('#xyz');

  });

  describe('validators service', () => {
    it('should correctly validate entity names', () => {
      expect(vs.isValidEntityName('b')).toBe(true);
      expect(vs.isValidEntityName('b   ')).toBe(true);
      expect(vs.isValidEntityName('   b')).toBe(true);
      expect(vs.isValidEntityName('bd')).toBe(true);
      console.log(AppConstants.INVALID_NAME_CHARS);
      expect(vs.isValidEntityName('')).toBe(false);
      expect(vs.isValidEntityName('   ')).toBe(false);
      expect(vs.isValidEntityName('x')).toBe(false);
      expect(vs.isValidEntityName('y')).toBe(false);
      expect(vs.isValidEntityName('bx')).toBe(false);
    });
```

Is something wrong here? I'm unable to mock the INVALID_NAME_CHARS property present in AppConstants. It still points to the original value(checked using the console.log written in the test)

Comment: Can you please add the component code as well. Is `AppConstants` injected into `ValidatorsService`?

Comment: This was a problem. The AppConstants wasn't injected into constructor rather it was used using new instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got the answer. There were two problems with this:

1. INVALID_NAME_CHARS is not a function, it's a class variable hence it does not returns anything. Instead we have to do a `appConstantsSpy.INVALID_NAME_CHARS = '#xyz'`.
2. I wasn't injecting the AppConstants into the constructor. The `{provide: AppConstants, useValue: spy}` works only if the service is injected into the constructor and hence the spy wasn't mocking. In fact, I was getting the original value itself. Also, the console statement would return the original value. We need to do `console.log(appConstantsSpy.INVALID_NAME_CHARS)`.